# convert link to hypertext or text

Tags: php, html, mysql

I'm struggling to convert links that from the database to hypertext.

Imagine a link string like http://example.com/file.txt

How do I change the echo statements to show the id filename on the download link?

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("example.com","username","pass","example.com");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM moviebase");

echo "<table border='1'>
<tr>
<th> ID </th>
<th> File Name </th>
<th> Link 1 </th>
<th> Link 2 </th>
</tr>";

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>" . $row['ID'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['filename'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['link1'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['link2'] . "</td>";
echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: Be careful. The link points to an exe file.

Comment: Sorry firsttime did not know it.. it was a example :(   i fixed it

Comment: Use something less potentially dangerous like a link to an image file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
echo "<td><a href='" . $row['link1'] . "'>download</a></td>";
```

Answer (score 1):

```
echo "<td><a href=".$row['link1'].">".$row['link1']."</a></td>";
echo "<td><a href=".$row['link2'].">".$row['link2']."</a></td>";
```